# Navbar separator between links

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make my navbar list items have a border on each side, but I want them still to be connected just like this:
http://prntscr.com/4wa4q4

When I try to add the border to both sides, they're spaced out and with no margin the 2 borders on each list item are together. How could I do it like in the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9Leecphh/

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
ul li:first-child{
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
}
ul li{
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #000;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: You could also use `display: inline-block` instead of table-cell.

Comment: @geebru inline-block causes the separation of the elements to be greater than a single pixel. I know there's some CSS to stop that from happening, but for the sake of simplicity, I went with using table-cell. You make a valid statement, though.

Comment: @J.Titus - Ah yeah I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add border-right on your li and border-left on li:first child. Then you can get it like in the screenshot.